# The expandLinkDepth is not working Tridion DXA 2.0

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

I am duplicating this [question] ([How to set nested component linking level in DXA](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17804/how-to-set-nested-component-linking-level-in-dxa)). My issue is with "R2 Render Content" Component Template in Web 8.5 and DXA 2.0

A developer created a component which has two levels of linked components and finds that the lowest level component does not fully render in the JSON coming from the Component Template.

Since DXA is based on DD4T which can be configured to do this, how can we set the number of levels in DXA?

Comment: Stupid question but are the templates changed on the context publication (if you have them localized) and checked in?

Comment: Check the Debug Log output of the CT/PT in Template Builder.

Comment: There is not much in the output log as such, no errors, no debug information. And just to add some more information to the question, these are custom schemas/models/views and we are not using core. When we reach the 3rd level while debugging, it throws an error saying "unable to map field xxx with property xxx". @Atila: Yes, everything is checked in.

Comment: Is the log level set to Debug in the Template Builder, when initially installed it's not?

Comment: changed the level to debug, and here is what it says:DefaultModelBuilder: Not expanding Component link because a Data Presentation exists: Schema 'level 2 schema name' (tcm:xxx)
DefaultModelBuilder: Encountered XLink '/List/list' -> Component tcm:xxx
DefaultModelBuilder: Not expanding Component link because a Data Presentation exists: Schema 'level 2 schema name' (tcm:xxx). Its not even giving details about level 2 components, so 3rd level is not in the picture at all

Comment: Can you update your Question and add thid debug output (formatted)? It is very hard to read like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can see in the debug output that the Component Links are not expanded because a Data Presentation exists.

DXA 2.0 supports so-called *dynamic expansion* of linked Components. With dynamic expansion, the linked Component is not expanded on CM-side, but published separately as a DCP (the so-called *Data Presentation*). Eventually, the linked Component will still get expanded, but this is done dynamically by the DXA Model Service.

You can choose for dynamic expansion by associating the Schema of the linked Component with the “Generate Data Presentation” Dynamic Component Template.

According to the log output, this is the case for your linked Components. If this is not desired, you should remove your Schema from the list of Related Schemas of the “Generate Data Presentation” CT.

The number of link levels to expand Component links statically can be configured as a parameter in TBBs “Render Page Content” and “Render Component Content”.

Answer (score 2):

Rick: Your comment did help us send us in the right direction, so thanks for that.

Our implementation has various instances of using components upto level of 3. 
As per Rick's comment, we decided to go with the "dynamic expansion" of linked components but our model was throwing a "null pointer exception" when it reached 3rd level. In order to resolve that, we increased the depth level of "Generate Data Presentation" to 3 which helped the model to get upto 3 level of our linked components.

"Render Page Content" and "Render Component Content" already had depth level of 3 which had not helped in our particular case.

Comment: sometimes your content ViewModel not required that expansion data on your webapp, those cases aproaches, • Set “dxa.errors.missing-entity-suppress” to “true”
This ensures that any missing information is at a level not needed for the views and this does not stop the model service from providing the Page Model Data with all available data