# DXA Resolver and data presentations + model building explained

Tags: dxa, model-service

Can someone please explain the role of the DXA Resolver and the Generate Data Presentation CT and how it affects building up the Page model?

I understand that you must link the desired Schema to said CT for it to be processed by the Resolver, I just don't understand why this is needed.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but DXA with the Model Service (2.0 and above) can handle both embedded and dynamic CPs perfectly fine, so why complicate things by introducing another concept? Are these data presentations treated differently by the Model Service in comparison to "regular" DCPs?

I have gone through the official documentation and various other online sources half a dozen times, but I seem to be having a brain freeze and am unable to grasp the concept at the moment, nor is everything properly explained/documented.

Some of the explanations say:

> The DXA Resolver ensures that the linked Dynamic Component Presentations are automatically republished

If I have a Page which has DCP added to it directly, [the DCP gets published  by default](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-3B23A2DC-71A0-4F96-A164-9E594068B687&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A589E3B1-E564-4409-B63C-CBF45D59CD6E.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3B23A2DC-71A0-4F96-A164-9E594068B687&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dembedded&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1565645020541&currentQuery=embedded&currentScope=) so why the need for the Resolver? Or is this not a valid use case?

OR

> When publishing a page, the resolver takes care of publishing a Dynamic Component Presentation (DCP) for every component on the page which is using a Schema linked to the Component Template titled “Generate Data Presentation”

So the Resolver adds a DCP to be published for all of those Components, the CT being be the Generate Data Presentation, right? But why would I need this? How does this affect the Model Service and its building the model?

And finally,

1. Does it make sense to to link any Schemas **which only have embedded CTs linked so far**, or should this be used only for Schemas which already have a dynamic Template associated?
2. Should all Schemas **which already have a dynamic Templates linked** be linked to the Generate Data Presentation? Or are they all just candidates, and some additional condition/use case must exist for this to make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not the only one who doesn’t understand the role of the DXA Resolver.

The keywords here are “Dynamic Expansion” and “Data Presentations”. Try searching for those terms on Stack Exchange and in DXA docs.

For example:

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v12/GUID-E4EB53CA-A83C-4D63-BB10-91567D632BB6

[The expandLinkDepth is not working Tridion DXA 2.0](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19407/the-expandlinkdepth-is-not-working-tridion-dxa-2-0/19418#19418)